# Splash Screen In Flutter on latest SDK 2.18.0

Tags: android, flutter, dart, splash-screen

I am new to  flutter and learn some basics of flutter, I want to make a splash screen, On that splash screen I want to show a custom icon, as per flutter doc I have to edit the style.xml inside the android hierarchy

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
</style>
```

but in my code, it always shows an error on drawable and says Cannot resolve symbol

```
'@drawable/launcher_background'
```

I follow this link https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen?tab=android-splash-alignment-kotlin-tab.

Please guide me on what I am doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In pubspec.yaml

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.16

flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/logo.png
  color: "#ffffff"
```

And then run:
'flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create'

I would suggest you use the native-splash dependency.
[Flutter-Native-Splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)

-> You can check out this video for a detailed explanation in just 2 mins [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dB0dOnc2k10)

Answer (score 0):

`launcher_background` is no longer used in Android 12.  If you are using your app with Android 12+, you should instead follow the directions in the [Android S](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen?tab=android-splash-alignment-kotlin-tab#android-s).  Or just use the flutter_native_splash as Yash advised.